# jQuery $(window).resize() not working when decreasing window's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I have a div with an id "main", I want to set its height using jQuery and making so that on `window.resize` its height is modified using a function but for some reason it works well only when increasing window's height, when decreasing it it doesn't work.

This is the JS:

```
function setMainH() {
    var docH = $(document).height();
    $("#main").height(docH - 40);
}

$(function() {
    setMainH();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    setMainH();
});
```

EDIT: the problem appears either increasing or decreasing

EDIT 2: the `resize()` event seem to be called correctly, I've tried with

```
console.log("resizing");
```

on resizing and it logs correctly so the problem isn't that.

Comment: `$(document).height();` is always the same regardless of window size. It's dependent on the content of the document.

Comment: Matteo, use `$(window).height()` if you want to get the height of the current viewport.

Comment: thanks! using $("html").height() as reference it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

So changing

```
var docH = $(document).height();
```

to

```
var docH = $(window).height();
```

will solve the problem.

Comment: This did not work for me until I added an HTML5 doctype. `<!doctype html>`

Comment: OMG @James, that was the problem. This was a stupid nuance that took me a couple hours to figure out. Thanks for posting your comment. It needs its own SO question & answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works fine in jsfiddle when running the JS without a wrapper in the body or head.

Demo of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/H5y5e/2/

You can however optimize your code a bit to clear-up the global space and cache the `$(document)` and `$('#main')` selectors so they doesn't have to be looked-up each `resize` event (which is a ton of events when the window resizes):

```
$(function() {
    var $document = $(document),
        $main     = $('#main');

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $main.height($document.height() - 40);
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H5y5e/1/

**UPDATE**

Also it seems like this can easily be done with just CSS (which is always good, takes care of the edge-case where someone has JS turned off):

```
#main {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    bottom   : 40px;
    width    : 100%;
}
```

Demo using just CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/H5y5e/3/

Comment: the css is cool but my body has a padding so i ca't give it a 100% height

Comment: If you want to go with JS that's your prerogative but in most cases CSS can be used. I just wanted to point that out in-case you were thinking this can only be done with JS.